# Table won't show up correctly

Tags: html, css

My table won't show up correctly. I've always been terrible at coding tables with CSS as they never perfectly work as they should. It would help to have another set of eyes just looking at the HTML and CSS.

**CSS**

```
table .domeSpecs {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: right;
    border: collapse;
    background-image: url("tableback.png") no-repeat right bottom;
    background-size: cover;
}
table .domeSpecs td {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
table caption {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table thead {
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    background-image: url("top.jgp") repeat-x top;
}
table thead tr {
    height: 40px;
}
table thead th {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
table thead th:first-of-type {
    background-image: url("topleft.jpg") no-repeat left top;
}
table thead th:last-of-type {
    background-image: url("topright.jpg") no-repeat right top;
}
table tfoot {
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("bottom.jpg") repeat-x bottom;
}
table tfoot tr {
    height: 40px;
}
table tfoot td:first-of-type {
    background-image: url("bottomleft.jpg") no-repeat left bottom;
}
table tfoot td:last-of-type {
    background-image: url("bottomright.jpg") no-repeat right bottom;
}
table tbody tr {
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
}
table tbody td:first-of-type {
    background-image: url("left.jpg") repeat-y left top;
}
table tbody td:last-of-type {
    background-image: url("right.jpg") repeat-y right top;
}
table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgba(152, 228, 215, 0.6);
}
table tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
table .firstColumn {
    width: 22%;
}
table .middleColumn {
    width: 28%;
}
table .lastColumn {
    22%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="domeSpecs">
    <caption>
        Building Models
    </caption>
    <colgroup>
        <td class="firstColumn"></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="middleColumn"></td>
        <td class="lastColumn"></td>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Total Sq. Ft.</th>
            <th>Sphere Size</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Call us about custom pricing!</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Class IA</td>
            <td>4700 square ft.</td>
            <td>50 ft. 5/8 sphere</td>
            <td>$150,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class IB</td>
            <td>4100 square ft.</td>
            <td>35 ft. 5/8 sphere</td>
            <td>$125,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class IIA</td>
            <td>3700 square ft.</td>
            <td>50 ft. 5/8 sphere</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class IIB</td>
            <td>3100 square ft.</td>
            <td>35 ft. 5/8 sphere</td>
            <td>$97,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class IIIA</td>
            <td>2600 square ft.</td>
            <td>45 ft. 5/8 sphere</td>
            <td>$84,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class IIIB</td>
            <td>2200 square ft.</td>
            <td>35 ft. 5/8 sphere</td>
            <td>$73,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what's wrong with your table? explain

Comment: The table is supposed to show up with styling and it's showing up blank. It shows the text and correct letter spacing and such, but doesn't show the styles created in the class or show the correct images.

Comment: Does this look correct? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvJmyd

I didn't change anything.

Comment: Is this the desired output?? http://jsfiddle.net/letmedoit/zc1s7srw/  Have a look at this link.

Comment: That's what the table is showing up as for me, which isn't how it's supposed to look. It SHOULD look like this: http://i67.tinypic.com/2q9jpf7.png

Comment: Did you try this ? table{ border:1px solid grey;     border-radius:8px;}